What is diagonalization with respect to sequences?

I am reading a paper and the phrase "Using diagonalization, choose a further subsequence..." is mentioned (see the above image). The only diagonalization I am familiar with is the linear algebra method, and based on the notation above it's not clear to me what the process of diagonalizing a (sub)sequence is and how it produces a new subsequence. When I have looked at sources online most of them seem to assume you already know what this means, and I was hoping someone could clearly explain:
(1) What does diagonlization mean when applied to a sequence?
(2) How does it produce a new subsequence?

This is unrelated to diagonalization in linear algebra, it is closer to diagonalization as in Cantor's diagonal argument.

I'm aware that it is not the same, but I'm having trouble finding a definition of what it means to diagonalize a subsequence.
